# По какому принципу лучше подгружать контент?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

На странице вывода постов из бд есть кнопка «показать ещё», которая подгружает ещё 6 постов. Как лучше сделать: 
1)сразу вывести на страницу все посты и скрыть часть из них,а потом показывать кнопкой по 6шт
2)или же при каждом нажатии кнопки обращаться к бд по Ajax и выводить по 6 шт? 
Второй вариант я уже реализовал, а если лучше сделать первый вариант, то подскажите как?

Comment: первый вариант очевидно лучше, потому что вдруг будет миллион записей, слишком долго будет грузить

Comment: Как раз таки при таком количестве записей страница не будет ли долго грузиться?

Comment: ой, второй, перепутал нумерацию

Comment: возможно имеет смысл собрать некоторую статистику действий пользователя. В зависимости от частоты появления контента и поведения пользователей, заранее подгрузить штук 30 новостей, и скрыть часть, а потом уже аяксом таскать остатки. 
Если у вас на сайте полтора землекопа, то можно не заморачиваться.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тут зависит от ситуации. Обычно я бы выбрал второй вариант.

Но есть еще такие варианты:

1. Если контент, который загружаете является основным (важным), я бы загрузил  сразу `12`, чтобы сократить ожидания пользователя. Обычно запрос `ajax`  забирает `19-230 мс` (в зависимости от сервера), это немного, но всё же. Логика простая, по 6 штук показывается, 6 штук скрыты. При нажатии кнопки, скрытые элементы  становятся видимыми и в этот момент догружаются следующие.
2. Изначально загружать все `ajax`-ом (даже первые 6 штук). Хорошо, когда скорость загрузки первой страницы имеет значение. Минус такого способа - дополнительные запросы к серверу.

Comment: Интересный способ и наверно визуально быстрее, так как подгрузка будет пока пользователь читает посты?

Comment: @Artur Han, верно. Также будет супер, если вы будите не верстку в ajax передавать, а именно json файл и рендерить с помощью джаваскрипта

Comment: эпичней было бы написать 19-231мс :D

Comment: teran, информация с логов)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всякий раз при нажатии на кнопку обращаться по AJAX к серверу. Только нужно внимательнее реализовать пагинацию чтобы при запросе из базы передавать правильные `skip` и `count`.

Comment: Что такое skip?

Comment: @ArturHan offset/limit иначе говоря

Comment: @ArturHan ну как что? Сколько пропустить и сколько взять. У тебя какая БД? `skip` и `count` это для MongoDB, в SQL-базах там другие какие-то методы, не помню. А, вон товарищ написал - `offset` и `limit`.